# Should I be keeping both stripe_id and card_id in a database?

Tags: php, security, stripe-payments

I'm new to stipe, and I'm just wondering if that I'm doing is a standard way of working with Stripe.

I have a very simple User model which I've added 2 new fields - `stripe_id` and `card_id`. When a user registers an API call to Stripe is made to generate a `stripe_id`. Then I ask for a credit card. I've used to basic stripe.js API to retrieve a `card_id`. I then store that card in the User model.

Is this safe to do this? I then card the user with their `stripe_id` and `card_id`.

I know that a user has more than one card, so eventually I'll move the cards a seperate table.

Comment: I look forward to an answer here, I am itching to use Stripe but have yet to have a client who wants it rather than Paypal :-/

Comment: The answer marked is a great answer. Stripe is incredibly easy to setup/use, but the downside is you're never sure what the correct way of handling situations is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the card later again store the `card_id`.

This is an example of how you would retrieve card info later in PHP

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve({CUSTOMER_ID});
$card = $customer->sources->retrieve({CARD_ID});
```

So you need both `stripe_id` and `card_id`.

---

If you only store `stripe_id` you can still list customer's all cards' information:

```
Stripe\Customer::retrieve({CUSTOMER_ID})->sources->all(array(
  "object" => "card"
));
```

Comment: But I'm not storing card details, I'm storing a token which represents a card. No card details are touching my server.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you for your input. It made me rethink my approach and I opted for the `stripe_id` method only, and removed the `card_id` is it's not need as the API can be queried to retrieve `card_id`s.